# Filtering resultset with codeigniter and datamapper

Tags: codeigniter, filter, resultset, codeigniter-datamapper

I got a little problem with datamapper, and I'd like to know if there is a quick solution.
Let's say I have this kind of data

**Groups table**

```
id   |   Name
1    |   admin
2    |   guest
3    |   editor
4    |   moderator
```

In my base controller I set a global field to see only the groups that are not admin

```
$this->groups_ = new Group();
$this->groups_->where('id >', 1)->get();

//so I can select the users that are not admin
$users = new User();
$users->where_related('group',$id,$this->groups_)->get();
```

Now in my controllers I'd like to filter the groups. For example I want to select only editors and guests (id between 1 and 4). So I would like to filter the initial result set... something like this

```
$this->groups_->where('id <',4)->get();
```

But it doesn't work. It returns ALL the group ids < 4 including admin.
What would be the right way to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A possible solution

Maybe I found a possible workaround by [cloning the datamapper object](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/clonecopy.html).
What I want to do is not to query the db multiple times, but I'd like to have a base resultset and refine the results.

So in my base controller I would do something like

```
$this->groups_ = new Group();
$this->groups_->where('id >', 1);//without getting the results

//so I can select the users that are not admin
$users = new User();
//here i'm getting the results from the clone
$users->where_related('group',$id,$this->groups_->get_clone()->get())->get();
```

And, as I left the object "open", without getting the results, I can use it in my controllers, as a base for my other "queries"... ok,they are actually new conditions of the first query.

```
//now the query return the groups between 2, as I set in the base controller
//and 4, set in the child controller
$this->groups_->where('id <',4)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, datamapper does not query objects or groups of objects. It queries the database. So when you do the second `get()`, you're executing a separate query on the database.

You can do this, but it will be an additional query:

```
$this->groups_->where('id >', 1)->where('id <', 4)->get();
```

or you can loop through `$this->groups_` after your first query in php and filter the set there and save as an array.